# Fully Qualified Name For Custom Android Attributes?

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm working on writing unit tests for a project and I am creating my custom component programmatically. The problem I'm running into is I need to pass in the fully qualified name for the attribute and I'm having trouble figuring out what that looks like for a custom attribute contained in my projects `attrs.xml` file.

```
@Test
public void test_ContextAndAttributeConstructorWithActivityTest() {
    Resources resources = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getResources();
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader = Shadows.shadowOf(resources).getResourceLoader();

    ArrayList<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
    attributes.add(new Attribute("com.example.application.view.ActivityActionButton:attr/activityName", "TestActivity.class", "com.example.application")); // this doesn't works
    attributes.add(new Attribute("android:attr/text", "Example Text", "com.example.application")); // this works
    RoboAttributeSet attributeSet = new RoboAttributeSet(attributes, resourceLoader);

    assertEquals(2, attributeSet.getAttributeCount());

    ActivityActionButton activityActionButton = new ActivityActionButton(context, attributeSet);

    assertEquals("Example Text", activityActionButton.getText()); // this passes

    assertEquals("TestActivity.class", activityActionButton.getActivityName()); // this fails
}
```

This is an example of what my code currently looks like with the package name obfuscated out by `com.example.application`.

My slimmed down `attrs.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="ActivityActionButton">
        <attr name="activityName" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

So what would the fully qualified name be for `activityName`?

Also: the component does in fact function correctly so I know my problem falls into what I'm passing in as the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's amazing what a new day and coffee can do. I was able to figure out what the fully qualified name for the custom attribute is and now my unit tests are passing.

In reference to my question the name is `com.example.application:attr/activityName`. So the working example would look like:

```
@Test
public void test_ContextAndAttributeConstructorWithActivityTest() {
    Resources resources = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getResources();
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader = Shadows.shadowOf(resources).getResourceLoader();

    ArrayList<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
    attributes.add(new Attribute("com.example.application:attr/activityName", "TestActivity.class", "com.example.application"));
    attributes.add(new Attribute("android:attr/text", "Example Text", "com.example.application"));
    RoboAttributeSet attributeSet = new RoboAttributeSet(attributes, resourceLoader);

    assertEquals(2, attributeSet.getAttributeCount());

    ActivityActionButton activityActionButton = new ActivityActionButton(context, attributeSet);

    assertEquals("Example Text", activityActionButton.getText());

    assertEquals("TestActivity.class", activityActionButton.getActivityName());
}
```